# Same low with different hole cards - who wins?

Tags: reading-hands, hand

Board: `A 4 5 7 J`

Two players declare a low.

Player A: `3 4 x x`

Player B: `A 3 x x`

Both players have the same low hand: `A 3 4 5 7`

Is this a tie or does Player B win with lower cards in his hand?

Answer (score 4):

It's a tie. Win/loss is always dependent on 5 cards. The only times differences in hand cards matter is when determining who gets the extra chip(s) in a split pot. (Though some casinos go by position instead of hand cards for this.)

Comment: Great answer. For what it's worth, in the UK I've only ever seen odd chips in a split pot awarded based on position (earliest position getting the extra chip) and never on hand content. However, there's very little O8 in the UK, so maybe there's somewhat of a game-specific divide as well as a geographical or cultural one.

Comment: @3N1GM4 - I probably should have said "Though **most** casinos go by position instead of hand cards". I think I've only seen suits determining the extra chip in one casino, and it was actually hold'em not O8, but I assume they would have had the same rule for O8 too (if there are multiple high hands and an extra chip).